# Stripe webhook API not extracting object from payload

Tags: kotlin, stripe-payments

There are many questions about Stripe webhooks on SO but I couldn't find one that fitted my issue.  I've written webhook code using Kotlin and the Spring Boot framework, and based the code on [Stripes example](https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks/quickstart), but as indicated by a comment in the code, am unable to extract the data object from the payload.  In my case, I would expect to extract an instance of `com.stripe.model.Charge`.

```
    @ResponseBody @PostMapping("/stripewebhook")
    fun index(@RequestHeader(value = "Stripe-Signature") stripeSecret: String, @RequestBody body: String): HttpStatus =
        try {
            val event = Webhook.constructEvent(body, stripeSecret, ourEndpointSecret)
            val deserialiser = event.dataObjectDeserializer
            if (deserialiser.`object` != null) {
                log.info("OBJECT: ${deserialiser.`object`}")  // outputs Optional.empty
                // For some reason, extraction of the payload from deserialiser does not work
                // so we use our own deserialisation, which does extract the object.
                val stripeObject = GsonConverter.fromJson(body, ReceiptAdviceWrapper::class.java).data.`object`
                when (event.type) {
                    "charge.succeeded" -> receiveReceipt(stripeObject, body)  // this is called
                    else -> {
                        log.error("Invalid type ${event.type}")
                        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
                    }
                }
            } else {
                log.error("Stripe object deserialisation failed: $stripeSecret // $body")
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
            }
        } catch (e: SignatureVerificationException) {
            log.error("signature", e)
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            log.error("body", e)
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log.error("payment", e)
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        }
```

The code above does work (i.e., it extracts and processes the charge details) but I would prefer to use Stripes means of extracting the `Charge` and not have to fall back to our own code.

We are using version 24.12.0 of Stripes Java library.

The question is:  why does `deserialiser.object` equal `Optional.empty` ?

Comment: Is your webhook endpoint receiving events on the API version 2023-10-16?

Comment: No:  version of 2020-08-27

Comment: stripe-java 24.* is pinned to the API version 2023-10-16. You need to configure your WebhookEndpoint to be pinned to that exact same API version. This means creating a new WebhookEndpoint with `api_version` set in the API. Once you do that you will be able to receive and deserialize the Event as expected.

Comment: @koopajah:  I'm using stripe-java 24.12.0 with a new webhook endpoint and `Webhook.constructEvent(...)` now throws a `SignatureVerificationException` with message _No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload" with API 2023-10-16_.

Comment: Okay so now you have to debug webhook signatures which are usually a problem with using the wrong secret or not passing the correct raw payload that exactly matches Stripe's data (up to the exact same space and comma ordering)

Comment: I overlooked that each webhook has its own signing secret and was using the wrong secret.